# Elasticsearch: Proximity search using 2 pre-tokenized arrays

Tags: python, elasticsearch, lucene

I want to be able to search within two separate arrays that are stored as separate fields.

For example, being to find the word married from preToke in between two PERSON values in candidate.

candidate = [u'PERSON', u'PERSON', u'PERSON', u'O', u'O', u'O', u'PERSON', u'PERSON', u'PERSON', u'O', u'O', u'PERSON', u'PERSON', u'PERSON', u'O', u'DATE', u'O']

preToke = [u'Lady', u'Bird', u'Johnson', u'was', u'born', u'as', u'Claudia', u'Alta', u'Taylor', u'and', u'married', u'Lyndon', u'B.', u'Johnson', u'in', u'1934', u'.']

Here is my mapping

```
`{
  "corpus" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "articles" : {
        "properties" : {
          "candidates" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index_options" : "offsets"
          },
          "lineNum" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "preToke" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index_options" : "offsets"
          },
          "sentence" : {
            "type" : "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

This is the query I tried, but it returns 0 results.

```
`searchResult = es.search(
    index="corpus",
    size=20,
    body={
      "query": {
        "span_near": {
          "clauses": [
            {
              "span_term": {
                "candidates": "person"
              }
            },
            {
              "field_masking_span": {
                "query": {
                  "span_term": {
                    "preToke": "married"
                  }
                },
                "field": "candidates"
              }
            },
            {
              "span_term": {
                "candidates": "person"
              }
            },
          ],
          "slop": 20,
          "in_order": "true"
        }
      }
    }
    )`
```